# magento Not valid template file /page/1column.phtml

Tags: templates, magento, magento-1.7

I had my site running fine on the devp. server. After I migrated the app to my production server. Everything worked until I added an extension and enabled it. The site still works but the product view page doesn't show up. Everytime I click on the product view page, this error is appended to my log file...

```
CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml
```

I have checked the file it is alright, just same as the one working on the development server. I've tried disabling the only plugin (custom menu) that I have and still the problem persists. I've tried increasing memory_limit but it doesn't help either.

Please help, I am stuck in the middle of nothing.

Comment: could it be the file permissions? My connect manager page was not showing either, I changed the permissions to 755 for the corresponding file and it showed up. Product details page is still blank, no error even after uncommenting ini_set() in index.php!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A common cause of this error is the use of symlinks without enabling this in the admin area…

```
System > configuration > developer > Template Settings
```

The error gets triggered in app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php around line 243 ( [see here](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php#L243) ) - so if its not an issue with symlinks then this would be a good place to start debugging.

If you are not using xDebug then where the exception gets caught around line 250 you should either log or var_dump the values of:

```
$includeFilePath
```

and

```
$this->_viewDir
```

Then make sure they both exist (paying attention to the case)

Failing that you might want to look at permissions.

Comment: Thanks, first of all. Enabling it doesn't work. Also,I have modified the core files just a little here and there and the system works fine on the local server! Its only when I install it on the production server, everything else works but the product view page is blank(tried installing twice)...

Comment: After a lot of headbanging the product page showed up when i incidently changed the template to 1 coloumn!

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '1' WHERE path = 'dev/template/allow_symlink';`

or

`INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/template/allow_symlink', '1');`